# How to show that сubed algebraic number is algebraic?

Tags: algebraic-number-theory

I have difficulty with that. But I can show that squared algebraic number is algebraic.

Let $a$ be algebraic number. Than there is a polynomial $P(x)$ of power $n$ with integer coefficients (the leading coefficient is $1$), and $P(a) = 0$.

Factorizing the $P$ we have: $P(x) = \Pi (x - a_{i})$.

Define polynomial $Q$:
$Q(x) = \Pi (x + a_{i})$.

$Q(x)$ has integer coefficients:
$Q(x) = \Pi (-((-x) - a_{i})) = (-1)^{deg(P)} P(-x)$.

$P(x) Q(x) = \Pi (x^2 - {a_i}^2)$.
So all powers for $x$ in the polynomial $P (x) Q (x)$ are even:
$P(x) Q(x) = R(x^2)$. And $R(x)$ has integer coefficients. And $R(a^2) = 0$. So $a^2$ is algebraic.

Comment: It may be more convenient to look at the field extensions $\mathbb{Q}[a]/\mathbb{Q}$ and $\mathbb{Q}[a^3]/\mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: Thanx. I will try to.

Comment: Unless you _absolutely_ want to find a polynomial for $a^3$ depending on a polynomial for $a$, you should instead prove that the product of two algebraic numbers over a field is again algebraic. (Your property will follow.)

Comment: IMHO, it is more difficult task.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The same trick works:

Let $Q(x) = \prod (x - a_{i}\omega)(x - a_{i}\omega^2)$, where $\omega$ is a primitive cubic root of unit.

Then $P(x) Q(x) = \prod (x^3 - {a_i}^3)=R(x^3)$ where $R(x)$ has integer coefficients. Then $R(a^3)=0$.

Comment: Thank you. I also thought about a cubic root of unit, but did't know how to use it.